# RepositoryItemReader doesn't find methods with arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm setting up an ItemRepositoryReader for the reader in a springBatch step.

```
public ItemReader<EcheanceEntity> reader(){
    RepositoryItemReader<EcheanceEntity> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<EcheanceEntity>();
    reader.setRepository(echeanceRepository);
    reader.setMethodName("findById");
    List parameters = new ArrayList();
    long a = 0;
    parameters.add(a);
    reader.setArguments(parameters);
    Map<String, Direction> sort = new HashMap<String, Direction>();
    sort.put("id", Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sort);
    return reader;
}
```

this is the line in my repository.

```
public interface EcheanceRepository extends JpaRepository<EcheanceEntity, Long>{


public EcheanceEntity findById(long id);

@Override
public List<EcheanceEntity> findAll();
```

If a use the method findAll(), so without any arguments, it works fine. But if I use the method findById(long id) I get "no such method exception, findById(java.lang.Long, org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest)" from the ItemRepositoryReader. The method works fine without using the reader when I'm testing it by using immediately the repository.

Thank you.

Comment: Because that method isn't there. Also what use is a find by id with a pageable argument? also `findById` or actually `findOne` is already provided as well as the `findAll` so I suggest you remove them from your own repository. They don't add anything.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even if I use findOne(long id), it works fine by using immediately from the repository, but not via the reader.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to use `findOne` in that reader nor does it make sense to have a `findOne` or `findById` which takes a `Pageable` argument. You are retrieving one element with an id, how are you going to sort/page on that?

Comment: Ok, I wanted to use an easier example and it's a bad one. EcheanceEntity does have a TypeEcheanceId field. I have in my repository this method: public List<EcheanceEntity> findByTypeEcheanceId(long l); 

Here I'm retrieving more elements.

Comment: Then add an argument to that method of type `Pageable` as the exception tells you...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a case of using the `RepositoryItemReader#setMethodName` method you need to add an argument of type `Pageable` in your repository method signature at last position:

```java
    public interface EcheanceRepository extends JpaRepository<EcheanceEntity, Long> {
    
        public Page<EcheanceEntity> findById(long id, Pageable pageable);
        ...
```

You can find description of it in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html#setMethodName-java.lang.String-

> ```
> public void setMethodName(java.lang.String methodName)
> ```
>
> Specifies what method on the repository to call. **This method must
> take `Pageable` as the last argument**.